# ToggleButton enable other toggle button automatically in listview in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview with toggle button and some data in listview. Let suppose I enable toggle at position 1 it works fine, and then I enable toggle at the position it automatically disable toggle at position 1. Please help me out.

code:-

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list_item, parent, false);
        listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
        listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        listViewHolder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    boolean isCheck = false;
    AllAppList model = listStorage.get(position);
    if (existingDataSet != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < existingDataSet.size(); i++) {
            if (model.getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName())) {
                isCheck = true;
            }
        }
        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isCheck);
    }
    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                        //Adding items in Dataset
                        AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);
                        whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());
                        whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());

                        if (existingDataSet!=null){
                            existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                        }else {
                            newDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(newDataSet);
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);
                    }
                }).show();

            } else {
                String jsonScore = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
                }.getType();
                existingDataSet = gson.fromJson(jsonScore, type);

                AllAppList model = listStorage.get(position);
                if (existingDataSet != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < existingDataSet.size(); i++) {
                        if (model.getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName())) {
                            existingDataSet.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }


    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **isCheck** variable is worked for the entire List.You have to make variable for each position.You can do this by making an boolean array,and make checked at that position.